# How to mock MainActivity using Mockito or another mocking framework?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I need to mock MainActivity as it is a parameter of an unit test I have. I tried `private val mockMainActivity: MainActivity = mock()`. However I get:

> Mockito cannot mock this class: class
> se.username.mmi.onboard.activities.MainActivity.
>
> Java               : 11 JVM vendor name    : JetBrains s.r.o. JVM
> vendor version : 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 JVM name           :
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JVM version        :
> 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 JVM info           : mixed mode OS name            : Linux OS version         : 6.2.0-31-generic
>
> You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create
> inlined mocks. You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations
> under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.
>
> Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
> create type org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Mockito
> cannot mock this class: class
> se.username.mmi.onboard.activities.MainActivity.
>
> If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please open an issue
> on GitHub.

How can I mock MainActivity then?

Comment: Did you read the limitation? "You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks. You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc."? Is it unclear?

Comment: Try looking at [Complete guide of creating mocks with mockito](https://davidvlijmincx.com/posts/complete_guide_of_creating_mocks_with_mockito/).

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test, you can then create a mock or a fake implementation of the MainActivity and pass it to SomeClass. This way, you're testing the logic in SomeClass without worrying about the complexities of MainActivity.

```
@Test 
fun testSomeClass() { 
val mockMainActivity = mock(MainActivity::class.java) 
val someClass = SomeClass(mockMainActivity) // Test the behavior of SomeClass }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it has the same error.